# How to control jobs of different families in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How to control jobs from different families

For example, when I perform the following actions in eclipse:

1. From the "Project" menu , select "Clean". Then the dialog appears I click on "OK" button.
2. Then " Cleaning all Projects " operation begins. In the middle of the operation I try to delete some file from my workspace.
3. the following dialog appears, "User operation is waiting" where the first operation which I did "Cleaning all operation" progress continues. And the second "Delete" operation will be blocked showing the "lock" symbol with message "Blocked: the user operation is waiting for cleaning all projects to complete". After completing the first operation only, the "Delete" operation dialog appears.

What I need?

I am trying to get the similar situation as above in my project.

1. I have created one job family for my project following the tutorial "On the Job eclipse".
2. I schedule the job to perform some operation in background.
3. as soon as the operation progresses, i tried to delete the file. As soon as I select "Delete" , Delete dialog appears. However, what I need is to Block this Delete operation until the first operation which I performed completes similar way as I told in the above example.

How it can be done using eclipse jobs.? I tried with `job.join()`, `job.setPriority()` and all....
If you have any idea please share

Answer (score 0):

You use 'scheduling rules' to define which jobs can run at the same time. A scheduling rule is a class which implements the `ISchedulingRule` interface.

A simple rule would be:

```java
public class MutexRule implements ISchedulingRule
{
  @Override
  public boolean isConflicting(ISchedulingRule rule)
  {
    return rule == this;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean contains(ISchedulingRule rule)
  {
    return rule == this;
  }
}
```

which will only allow one job with this rule to run at a time. Use like this:

```java
ISchedulingRule rule = new MutexRule();

Job job1 = new ....
Job job2 = new ....

job1.setRule(rule);
job2.setRule(rule);

job1.schedule();
job2.schedule();
```

Note that `IResource` extends `ISchedulingRule` and implements a rule to stop two jobs accessing the same resources at a time.

So to have only one job modifying the workspace at a time you can use:

```java
ISchedulingRule rule = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
```

(since `IWorkspaceRoot` extends `IResource`). Eclipse uses this rule for many jobs.

You can also use `IResourceRuleFactory` to create rules for controlling access to resources.

```java
IResourceRuleFactory factory = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRuleFactory();
```

There is also a `MultiRule` class which allows you to combine several scheduling rules.